# what does "belt up" mean in "He could belt up to tenor high F (F5)"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

In the Wikipedia article of Freddie Mercury, we read:

> He could **belt up** to tenor high F (F5).

link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddie_Mercury

I found nothing useful in the dictionary, all dictionaries says "belt up" means something like "be quiet", but that makes no sense here.

Comment: There is a direct link on the page you reference to the technique of 'belting'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belting_(music)

Comment: The meaning of belt aside - you're misreading. There is an unspoken comma between belt & up separating the clauses. (He could belt), (up to F5) ...Compare to "He could run up to 5 miles a day"

Comment: Also look up *belt out*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Belt up" here is a colloquial phrase meaning he could make his voice go up to tenor high F. "Belt" is sometimes used to express a loud noise a person makes, usually associated with singing.